# How to get a collection of page elements?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, webforms

On Page_Init, I check if Button1 was pressed, if so I create a series of LiteralControls in a Panel, called Panel1:

```
   Panel1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<table>"));

   Panel1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<tr>"));
   Panel1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<td>Header 1</td>"));
   Panel1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<td>Header 2</td>"));
   Panel1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<td>Header 3</td>"));
   Panel1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</tr>"));

   Panel1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<tr>"));
   Panel1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<td>Data 1</td>"));
   Panel1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<td>Data 2</td>"));
   Panel1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"txtCode3\"></td>"));                
   Panel1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</tr>"));

   Panel1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</table>"));
```

I have a second button, that on click, I want to fill a NameValueCollection (or any other list) with all table cell elements (or values).

How can I do this?
I've tried:

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
             NameValueCollection coll = Request.Form;
    }
```

But this only gives me:

```
AllKeys:
    [0] "_VIEWSTATE"
    [1] "_EVENTVALIDATION"
    [2] "Button2"
    [3] "txtCode3"
```

As you can see, I can't get all cell elements.
I should get:

```
AllKeys:
    [0] "_VIEWSTATE"
    [1] "_EVENTVALIDATION"
    [2] "Button2"
    [3] Header 1
    [4] Header 2
    [5] Header 3
    [6] Data 1
    [7] Data 2
    [3] "txtCode3"
```

Thank you.

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13259505/how-to-preserve-user-input-in-literal-control-on-postback

Comment: @Tariqulazam: This is a different question. The question you mentioned I asked how to get the text entered in the text box. Now I'm asking how to get the entire collection of elements into a NameValueCollection (or any other list).

Comment: You should then probably narrow it down to your current problem. Getting entire collection of elements into a NameValueCollection has nothing to do with what you are doing in page_init. Request.Form itself a namevaluecollection. Use F12 to see what a property or method supposed to return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I as able to achieve this by switching to an <asp:Table> instead of a plain html table.